# Stuck with mysql query and JOINs

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables. In table#1 there is `IDotac` and `IDmajka` and `IDgolub`. I need to find `brojgoluba` from table#2 that matches those 3 fields in table#1.

for example in table#1 ID=28

(table#1)IDgolub=1, (table#2)brojgoluba=06557-07-681

(table#1)IDmajka=3, (table#2)brojgoluba=2081-01-271

(table#1)IDotac=2, (table#2)brojgoluba= 07216-05-552

```
    SELECT 
    Otac.brojgoluba AS o_brojgoluba,
    Majka.brojgoluba AS m_brojgoluba, 
    mg_golub.ID
    FROM mg_golub
    LEFT JOIN mg_popis_golubova AS Otac ON (Otac.IDotac=mg_golub.ID)
    LEFT JOIN mg_popis_golubova AS Majka ON (Majka.IDmajka=mg_golub.ID)
    WHERE mg_popis_golubova.IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK'
```

table#1

[image]

table#2

[image]

**Note:** problem here is that in table#2 I have to pick some more info other than `brojgoluba` and I have some fields in table#2 that are linked to other tables

Comment: I can't follow your question - can you try to reword it?

Comment: better now? if not I will try to change it completely

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, brojgoluba FROM 
table1, table2
WHERE 
table1.Idkorystnik=1 AND     table2.Idkorystnik=1 AND
(table1.IDgolub=table2.ID OR
 table1.IDMajka=table2.ID OR
 table1.IDotak=table2.id)
```

Comment: that is not the thing I need

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be well on the way to your answer.  Is this it?

```
SELECT Otac.brojgoluba AS o_brojgoluba,
       Majka.brojgoluba AS m_brojgoluba, 
       Dotac.brojgoluba as d_brojgoluba,
       mg_golub.ID
FROM mg_golub LEFT JOIN
     mg_popis_golubova Otac
     ON (Otac.IDotac=mg_golub.ID) LEFT JOIN
     mg_popis_golubova Majka
     ON (Majka.IDmajka=mg_golub.ID) LEFT JOIN
     mg_popis_golubova Dotac
     on (Dotac.IDmajka=mg_dotac.ID)
WHERE mg_popis_golubova.IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK'
```

Alternatively, you might want to filter all the matching tables by the `where` clause.  You should be doing this in the `on` clauses, so you don't lose any rows:

```
SELECT Otac.brojgoluba AS o_brojgoluba,
       Majka.brojgoluba AS m_brojgoluba, 
       Dotac.brojgoluba as d_brojgoluba,
       mg_golub.ID
FROM mg_golub LEFT JOIN
     mg_popis_golubova Otac
     ON Otac.IDotac=mg_golub.ID and  and Otac.IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK' LEFT JOIN
     mg_popis_golubova Majka
     ON Majka.IDmajka=mg_golub.ID and Majka.IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK' LEFT JOIN
     mg_popis_golubova Dotac
     on Dotac.IDmajka=mg_dotac.ID and Dotac.IDkorisnik='$ID_KORISNIK'
```

Comment: I think it is not right because mg_popis_golubova=Otac and It can't take brojgoluba from mg_popis_golubova because I don't have any field named brojgoluba there